# Laravel API - Vue SPA | How fetch image securely and display it in img tag?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a Laravel 7 API back-end and a Vue 2 SPA. Both are two different repositories/servers. And I have some images/files which I want to expose only to authenticated users from my API.

#### Laravel API Code:

So I have a route `/api/v1/users/{user}/profile_picture`:

```php
    /**
     *  Returns profile picture if user has access to it or it is user's own picture
     * 
     * @param  Request
     * @param  User
     * @return HTTP response
     */
    public function getProfilePicture(Request $request, User $user) {
        if($user->is($request->user()) || $request->user()->can("View All Images")) {
            return response()->file(storage_path('app/avatars/'.$user->avatar));
        }else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => $request->user()->name . ' does not have the permission to access this picture'
            ], 403);
        }
    }
```

I tested this route in postman and it works fine (I get image preview in postman). However I'm failing to display this image in an `<img>` tag in my Vue SPA.

#### Vue Code:

```js
<template>
 ...
 <img key="onlineImg" :src="'data:image/jpeg;base64, ' + profile_pic" alt="user-img" width="40" height="40" />
...
</template>

<script>

import jwt from '@/http/requests/auth/jwt/index.js';


export default {
  data () {
    return {
      profile_pic: ""
    }
  },

  mounted() {
      jwt.profile_picture_get().then((response) => {
        this.profile_pic = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64');
      });
  },
}
```

No matter how I try to assign the response to `:src=` it does not work. I get a broken image thumbnail when the request finally completes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do You mean by "broken" and "not work"? What do You see in debug console and in html course inside src="" ?